# Setting $PS3 has no effect

Tags: bash, terminal

I'm experimenting with changing `PS3`, I'm expecting the following script will cause the new value to be shown when run:

```
select i in red blue green exit
do
  case $i in
    red) echo "Red";;
    blue) echo "Blue";;
    green) echo "Green";;
    exit) exit;;
  esac
done
```

Then I change PS3 value.

```
PS3=">"
```

But when I run the script the default `#?` is used.

[image]

Not sure what I'm missing, is there a limit on what values can be used?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Either export the variable so the subshell that runs the script sees its new value

```
export PS3='>'
./select.sh
```

or set it only for the script

```
PS3='>' ./select.sh
```